# Ignore UIPanGesture in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UINavigationController` that has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

```
MyNavController.m
...

menuGesture.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:menuGesture];
```

It works great, but I need to ignore that `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in one of my `topViewControllers`. I tried `self.view.gestureRecognizers = nil`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to enable/disable some gesture recognizers that you have added in your controllers, one approach would be exposing that gesture recogniser through a property and then enable/disable it at will:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign/weak) UIPanGestureRecognizer* myGestureRecognizer;
```

...

```
[(MyNavController*)myController.navigationController myGestureRecognizer].enabled = NO;
```

(of course, your `menuGesture` would be stored in myGestureRecognizer for this to work).

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Comment: Also, how do I access my `gestureRecognizer` from a `topViewController`

Comment: @JoshuaDwire: I expanded my answer. The idea is that if you need to enable/disable a feature in your class, you expose a property for doing it... hope this helps...

Comment: from any view controller displayed inside a navigation controller, you can use the `navigationController` property to access the latter... of course, `navigationController` will need some cast to work correctly, since it is only a generic `UINavigationController`...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to subscribe to the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and then determine if the gesture should be allowed in [gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009280-CH1-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

try like this :UINavigationController has a method called

```
- (void)removeGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the `gestureRecognizer`. Just want to ignore it on one `UIViewController`